# I am seeing if the items in list two is triple the data in list one in every position

Tags: python

```
for i in range(0,len(data1)):
  if data1[i] == data2[i] *3:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

How can I see if every item in data1 is tripled in the same spot as data2 I am stuck I think I have the right loop.

Comment: Try using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) — `return all(condition for variable in sequence)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return anything, when data IS trippled as you will break your loop right away. You should only return `False` when it is not and then return `True` if nothing was falsy.

```
for i in range(len(data1)):
    if data1[i] != data2[i] * 3:
        return False
return True
```

Here is a oneliner:

```
return all(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1] * 3, zip(data1, data2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can do this :

```py
for i in range(0,len(data1)):
    if data1[i] != data2[i] *3:
       return False

return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data1==[3*i for i in data2]
```

Comment: OP is trying to check if all values are triples, not to create a list of tripled values.

Comment: My code doesn't create anything, it checks what OP wants (it's == not =)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your technique seems pretty fine to me, except for a few small mistakes in the code itself. I'll show you your own code with notes, then the new corrected code:

```
#your code

for i in range(0,len(data1)):
               ^
#if you will start from 0 anyway, it's always better to just leave it out.

  if data1[i] == data2[i] *3:
                       ^^^^
#here, i would change data2[i] to int before multiplying also change data1, just to be safe.

    return True
  else:
    return False
```

now here's the full correction:

```
#correction

for i in range(len(data1)):
  if int(data1[i]) == int(data2[i]) *3:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

postscript:
sometimes an error would occur in the `if int(data1[i]) == int(data2[i]) *3` line (idk why) but if this ever happens just add a line before it containing an int of i*3.

```
num = int(i)
num2 = int(i*3)
```

note that this has to be inside the for loop but before the conditions.

Happy coding

**if this didn't work..well im not a professional so sorry in advance